# What's the equivalent of clusterPower's 2mean function from version 0.6.111?

Tags: r

Trying to figure out what equates to version `0.6.111`'s function `crtpwr.2mean` from [this page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/clusterPower/versions/0.6.111/topics/crtpwr.2mean)

It's deprecated in the newest version (0.7) and I'm confused as to what is the corresponding function.

Comment: Shouldn’t this question be posed to the package authors? After of course reading the package’s News items if they are present.

Comment: You should offer a programming question. This is not really one that allows any code to be directed at it. There's no clear problem, no data, no illustration of how the previously available function was used, not even a statement that an effort was made to load  that function from an old copy of the package.